# Getting 400 bad request error in Jquery Ajax POST in jsp file

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, http-status-code-400

I am performing simple crud operation during this I am getting 400 bad request error on console 
i.e. POST  http://localhost:8080/student/getDetails  400

my code :

```
<body>

<form > 

Enter Student id:  <input type="number" id="id" name="id"/><br/>
<button id="selectButton" onclick="getStudent()">Get Student</button>

</form>

<script type="text/javascript"
    src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getStudent() {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url : "/student/getDetails",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", 
            dataType: "json", 
            success : function(data) 
            {
                alert(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                alert(data);
        }
        });
    }
</script>


</body>
```

Comment: Does it work if you try the request from a normal form submit, or a REST client?  Since you're not giving it any data, you don't have to give it the contentType.  Also since they request is "getDetails", why are you doing a POST?

Comment: @Taplar : It is working for normal form submit. But not working when using ajax. As per Post is concern, I tried for GET also.. But nothing worked. :(

Comment: Well, your ajax request is not sending the id from the form on it... ?

Comment: Actually I have used @RequestMapping("/getDetails" , method = RequestMethod.POST )
 public ModelAndView getDetails(@RequestParam int id) 
I am trying to get id using @RequestParam....

Comment: Right, but that's your server side logic.  Not the ajax.  Your ajax is literally not sending any data.  It's just hitting the endpoint.  http://learn.jquery.com/ajax/jquery-ajax-methods/